# Windows Phone XAML Style for Store - Apps page

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

[image]I am trying to get the same layout as the subsection in store-apps-spotlight, the one showing images with the 2 subheadings. can anyone perhaps help me, the best I could do was create stackpanels with the individual elements but this feels somewhat separate, and would like to be more like a "unit", cause I would like to get data from a server and dynamically display the amount of tiles there are info, this is what I got so far:

```
 <phone:PanoramaItem Header="third item" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!--Double wide Panorama with large image placeholders-->
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10">
                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="175" Height="175" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,10,10" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Heading 1" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="15" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Heading 2" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="12" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="175" Height="175" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,10,10" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Heading 1" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="15" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Heading 2" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="12" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="175" Height="175" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,10,10" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Heading 1" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="15" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Heading 2" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="12" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="175" Height="175" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,10,10" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Heading 1" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="15" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Heading 2" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="12" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="175" Height="175" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,10,10" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Heading 1" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="15" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Heading 2" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="12" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="175" Height="175" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,10,10" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Heading 1" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="15" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Heading 2" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="12" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

any logic ideas, or xaml styling ideas will be much appreciated

Comment: Post a pic of what you're after, it sounds like either an ItemsControl or maybe a ListBox would remedy it for you with lots less clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Could you a single `Canvas` and set the `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` property of all the objects to give the desired location on the page?